# How to get the angle of correction in ORB detection OpenCV ++?

Tags: c++, opencv, computational-geometry

```
// Find homography

h = findHomography( points1, points2, RANSAC );

// Use homography to warp image

warpPerspective(im1, im1Reg, h, im2.size());
```

I see here that the output image is warped but I wanted to know by how much the angle is changed with respect to the input image?

Comment: There is no simple "angle" of a perspective transformation and also the question as shown here has nothing to do with ORB or detection.

Comment: yea late reply but i forgot to mention i was using this guide here https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/. i now understand it was the euclidean transform i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What angle?

Perspective changing would not be defined with a simple rotation. That angle you are looking for, exists in **Euclidean** (rigid) transformation which preserves the euclidean distance between every pair of points.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the help. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look at the documentation of the API before using it.[link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))

the variable h which is a 3x3 matrix has the transformation.